# Get value from input and put in a string array lotto game

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to make a lottery game where I generate 8 random hexadecimal numbers like 15 4A FF 45 77 C3 EE 7E and introduce my numbers.I want to find how many numbers I guessed. I take the values from input and put them into an array and insert space between numbers, then splitting the result.The same with the numbers generated but I can't figure out I don't get the correct result.

```
<section id="section2">
    <h2>Internet Loto</h2>
    <button onclick="genHexString();">Genereaza numere</button>
    <br />
    <button onclick="tryAgain()" ;>Incearca din nou</button>
    <p id="loto"></p>
    <p class="numere">
        <label for="nr1">Nr1:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr1">
        <label for="nr2">Nr2:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr2">
        <label for="nr3">Nr3:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr3">
        <label for="nr4">Nr4:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr4">
        <label for="nr5">Nr5:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr5">
        <label for="nr6">Nr6:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr6">
        <label for="nr7">Nr7:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr7">
        <label for="nr8">Nr8:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr8">
    </p>
</section>
```

function genHexString() {

```
var output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    output += (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML += '&nbsp';
    if (i % 2 != 0 && i < 15) {
        output += '&nbsp'; // space for display each number as pair of 2 characters
    }
}

var res = output.split(" "); 
document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML = "Winning numbers: " + output;

var input = "";
for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    var x = "nr" + i;
    input += document.getElementById(x).value + '&nbsp';
}
var res2 = input.split(" ");
document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML += "<br/>Your numbers: " + res2;
var count = 0;
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        if (res[i] == res2[j]) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML += "<br/>Numere ghicite: " + count;
```

}

Comment: input should be number or hexadecimal?

Comment: it should be a number like Nr1:AA Nr2:EF etc, I think it could be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

includes function can come in hand.

Try this

```js
function genHexString() {

var output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    output += (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML += '&nbsp';
    if (i % 2 != 0 && i < 15) {
        output += '&nbsp'; // space for display each number as pair of 2 characters
    }
}
document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML = "Winning numbers: " + output;
var count = 0;
var input = "";
console.clear();
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    var x = `nr${i}`;
    let value=document.getElementById(x).value;
    if(output.includes(value) && value)
       count++;
    input += value + '&nbsp';
}
document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML += "<br/>Your numbers: " + input;


document.getElementById("loto").innerHTML += "<br/>Numere ghicite: " + count;
}
```

```css
label{
margin-left:10px;
}
input{
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:30px;
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<section id="section2">
    <h2>Internet Loto</h2>
    <button onclick="genHexString();">Genereaza numere</button>
    <br />
    <button onclick="tryAgain()" ;>Incearca din nou</button>
    <p id="loto"></p>
    <p class="numere">
        <label for="nr1">Nr1:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr1">
        <label for="nr2">Nr2:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr2">
        <label for="nr3">Nr3:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr3">
        <label for="nr4">Nr4:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr4">
        <label for="nr5">Nr5:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr5">
        <label for="nr6">Nr6:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr6">
        <label for="nr7">Nr7:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr7">
        <label for="nr8">Nr8:</label>
        <input pattern="[A-Z0-9]{2}" id="nr8">
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi if this answer was helpful. Please upvote and mark it as answer.